# Pronunciation of the word "compte"

Tags: prononciation

I have only studied French for a week. I run into the word "compte" and when I check my dictionary it appears that it is pronounced as: "\kɔ̃t\". I have also run the word through various speech-machines and I get an impression that there is a slight "m"-sound but I am not 100%.

Perhaps any of you can tell me if it is general rule that words beginning with: "com" suppress the "m"?

Comment: It's the same sound for a majority of French user as "con + consonant (other that other "n", or "m" in our case to double it)". It's the rule that transforms the "n" before a "p" or a "b".The 'p' is also mute in our case, and its presence is here for etymological reasons ("computus" from Latin).

Comment: The best audio resource for French pronunciation, in my opinion, is [Forvo](http://fr.forvo.com/word/compte/#fr). Real French-speaking people, not speech-machines. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a French person, I'd say it is a specific case: the root "comp-" is never pronounced with a "m". For instance, the "m" is silent in "comparable", "compatibilité", etc. It is also silent in "comte".

However if there is a double "m", then it is pronounced: "commutation", "commère", "commentaire".

Comment: In the latter examples, the "m" is indeed pronounced but you should state there is no nasalisation: /ɔ̃/. The "o" is simply pronounced /ɔ/ or /o/, depending on the accent.

Answer (score 1):

*Compte* is pronounced the same way than *conte* and *comte*.

The problem for you is the "-omp-" part: in this case it's pronounced like a "on".

The same sound than in *b**on***, *mais**on***, *garç**on***, *leç**on***...

Answer (score 0):

The classical grammar rule says :

*"before m, b, p, one always replaces the n by an m. The only exception is the word 'bonbon'"*

The French prefix "con" is also used in English, and means "with". Without that rule, we would write *"conmerce","conbinaison",  "conptable"*, but the rule being applied, we write *"commerce","combinaison","comptable"*,